# Concat sequence number to each row in a group using Pandas and R

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like as shown below (Both R and Python data frame codes are given below)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14]})
df['enc_id'] = [1134567890,1134567890,1134567890,3456789210,3456789210,3456789210,3456789210,5643271890,5643271890,5643271890,5643271890,5643271890,2468013579,2468013579,2468013579]

person_id <- c(11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14)
enc_id <- c(1134567890,1134567890,1134567890,3456789210,3456789210,3456789210,3456789210,5643271890,5643271890,5643271890,5643271890,5643271890,2468013579,2468013579,2468013579)
df <- data.frame(person_id, enc_id)
```

I would like to concat a sequence number to `enc_id` for each person

I wrote something like below in Python

```
df['new_enc_id'] = df['enc_id'].map(str) + (df.groupby('person_id').cumcount()+1).map(str)
```

Can you help me with the below questions?

1. How can I do this in R?
2. Any elegant way to do this in Python?

I expect my output to be like as shown below. You can see that `sequence number` is concatenated for each group and `not added`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R

```
df = df %>% group_by(person_id) %>% dplyr::mutate(new_enc_id = paste0(enc_id,row_number()) )
```

Comment: May I know why is there a space between `enc_id` and `sequence number`?

Comment: @TheGreat change paste to paste0 ~

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is good, only I use `astype` for convert to strings:

```
df['new_enc_id'] = (df['enc_id'].astype(str) + 
                    (df.groupby('person_id').cumcount()+1).astype(str))
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `transform` + `ave`

```
df <- transform(
  df,
  new_enc_id = paste0(new_enc_id, ave(1:nrow(df), person_id, FUN = seq_along))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

within the `R` space, you could get the same result with `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)

df[, paste0(enc_id,row.names(.SD)), by=person_id]
```

For the python solution, @jezrael's solution suffices.